# What's the advantage of using ArrayAdapter in android?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

Few things in android can be done using directly XML Layouts then why do we use ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Using `ArrayAdapter` is very short way to bind adapter in less code. If you are using `ArrayList` of `Object`, clearly `ArrayAdapter` is a better way than using `BaseAdapter` as -

`BaseAdapter` require a little more code.

Say for an example, Two lines of code and your adapter binding is done -

```
ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = 
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
listview.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confused between differentiating a Layout and an Adapter. While a Layout is what you would inflate and display, Adapter is the one that would facilitate **populating the the data** *for* the displayed view. Adapter takes on the role of a mini-controller as in a MVC pattern.

Now, you want to work without an Adapter, you can! But if you have a list of data to display, you would ultimately use a `List`. An ArrayAdapter basically wraps this list as source of data and provides it to the view when asked for.

You can control how the data comes to the view by performing any pre-processing if you want. You can make the changes in the data set invisible to the View by managing them under the hood. All this is possible because of an Adapter and that's the Advantage of using an Adapter.